# Native UI component not showing up in React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm trying to get the following custom native UI component show up in React Native

**RectangleView.java**

```
public class RectangleView extends View {


    Paint mRectPaint;

    public RectangleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mRectPaint = new Paint();
        mRectPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        // mRectPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        postInvalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500, mRectPaint);
    }
}
```

This is the wrapper in my React code

**RectangleView.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { requireNativeComponent, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const RCTRectangleView = requireNativeComponent('RCTRectangleView', RectangleView);

export default class RectangleView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
        
            <View>
                <Text> Hello world </Text>
                <RCTRectangleView {...this.props} />
            </View>

        );
    }
}

RectangleView.propTypes = {
    ...View.propTypes,
    color: PropTypes.string
};
```

I see "Hello World" but I don't see the blue rectangle I'm expecting to see. The only messages in my console are

> 05-15 16:18:02.299 10937 10969 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: View.propTypes has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version of ReactNative. Use ViewPropTypes instead.
>
> 05-15 16:18:02.316 10937 10969 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "CustomViewTest" with appParams: {"initialProps":{},"rootTag":1}. **DEV** === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF

I'm guessing there needs to be a way to specify the width and the height of the custom view? Unable to find a concrete example online that does something like this.

Comment: use ```import { requireNativeComponent, View, Text, ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';```

Comment: did you ever find out what was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
<RCTRectangleView style={{ width: "75%, height: "20%" }} />
```

I seriously worked for 2 hours in the net and finally found the way.
Just had to use the style prop to adjust the width and height.
Now, I am very happy and also very irritated that i did not think of this before.
Hope this helps any other guy that comes here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to add width,height with style prop or you can give flex:1 or if you want send all style as Reactpropgroups